# Proving a Property of a Random Walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Consider a process $X_t$, given by $X_0 = 1$ and $X_t = X_{t-1} + B_t$ where

\begin{align}
B_t = 
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        1, \ \ \text{with probability } \frac{p}{2} \\
        0, \ \ \text{with probability } \frac{1}{2}\\
        -1, \ \ \text{with probability } \frac{q}{2}
    \end{array}
\right\}
\end{align}

and $p+q=1$

Consider the event $E_k = \{X_s = 0 \text{ for some } s>0, X_0 = k\}$. Explain why $\mathbb{P}(E_2) = \mathbb{P}(E_1)^2$.

---

So, I think this is a random walk, but it's not a simple random walk as $B_t$ can take 3 values (correct me if I'm wrong!).

A hint I have been given for this question is to use the same concept that is used to show this in a simple random walk, but this requires the assumption that given the current state $X_s$, the next state $X_{s+1}$ is independent from the history of the random walk. But, in my course we haven't seen this result for anything but a simple random walk and we have only seen simple random walks so I'm a bit stumped with this...

If I were to assume this could I write

$$ \begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(E_2) 
&= \mathbb{P}(\exists 0 < s_1 < s_2 \text{ s.th } X_{s_1} = 1 | X_0 = 2) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(X_{s_2} = 0 | X_{s_1} = 1) \mathbb{P}(X_{s_1} = 1 | X_0 = 2) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(E_1)^2
\end{align} $$

Where the last equality is because
$$ \begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(E_1) = \mathbb{P}(X_{s_i} = k-i | X_{s_{i-1}} = k - i + 1)
\end{align} $$

Is this correct? And, if so why? If anyone could point me to a good resource on this, introductory stochastic processes I would really appreciate it. I'm struggling to find anything that isn't too advanced for me and I really want to get my head around these basics before moving on to Markov Chains.

Comment: That $X_{s+1}$ depends only on $X_s$ and not the history of previous $X_a$ is just from the definition of $X_t$.

Comment: Have you ever learned about (strong) Markov property?

Comment: @SangchulLee No, I only have basic 2nd year undergraduate probability and statistics knowledge, and in terms of stochastic processes I really only understand simple random walks and the Bernoulli process, I am familiar with pgfs if that's useful

Comment: @aschepler Thank you! D'oh! It's obvious now, so I can use my workings above to show the claim?