# Calculating the Probability of an Event in a Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-probability

Consider a process $X_t$, given by $X_0 = 1$ and $X_t = X_{t-1} + B_t$ where

$$ 
B_t = 
\begin{cases}
        1 \ \ &\text{ with probability } \frac{p}{2} \\
        0 \ \ &\text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2} \\
        -1\ \ &\text{ with probability } \frac{q}{2}
\end{cases}
$$
and $p+q=1$.

Consider the event $E_k = \{X_s = 0 \text{ for some } s>0, X_0 = k\}$.

Calculate $\mathbb{P}(E_1)$ by conditioning on the outcomes of $B_1$.

---

So here is my attempt:

We have $E_1 = \{X_s = 0 \text{ for some } s>0, X_0 = 1\}$ and so conditioning on the outcome of $B_1$ we have

$$ \begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(E_1)
&= \mathbb{P}(E_1 | B_1 = 1)\mathbb{P}(B_1 = 1) 
\\
&\qquad + \mathbb{P}(E_1 | B_1 = 0)\mathbb{P}(B_1 = 0) + \mathbb{P}(E_1 | B_1 = -1)\mathbb{P}(B_1 = -1)\\[2mm]
&= \frac{p}{2} \mathbb{P}(X_t \text{ eventually reaches zero } | X_1 = 2)\\ 
&\qquad+ \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{P}(X_t \text{ eventually reaches zero } | X_1 = 1) + 1 \cdot \frac{q}{2}\\[2mm]
&= \frac{p}{2} \mathbb{P}(E_1)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{P}(E_1) + \frac{q}{2}
\end{align} 
$$
Which gives us a quadratic in $\mathbb{P}(E_1)$, so

$$
\mathbb{P}(E_1) = \frac{1}{p} - \sqrt{\frac{q}{p}} 
\qquad\text{ OR }\qquad \sqrt{\frac{q}{p}}
$$

But I'm stuck as to how to decide on a solution? I assume there must be some constraints which force one of these solutions but I don't know what..

---

EDIT: I've been told that I should get the solution $\mathbb{P}(E_1) = \frac{q}{p}$ for $p > q$ or $\mathbb{P}(E_1) = 1$ for $p \leq q$ and that my method is along the right lines, but I'm still really struggling to get this

Comment: In the definition of $E_k$ we have the $k$-dependency at a place, that is feeling wrong. Well, we have $X_0=1$. So why this cumbersome notations, when all the time we use only $E_1$? An $E$ instead would make typing easier. Also, why do we have that $\Bbb P(E_1)^2$ term?

Comment: @dan_fulea I'm just using the notation that is being used in my stochastic processes class, I'm new to this are and so don't know any different notations. The $\mathbb{P}(E_1)^2$ term comes from here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4801683/997524 as $\mathbb{P}(E_1)^2 = \mathbb{P}(E_2)$

Comment: @dan_fulea I think perhaps in my course we are continuing to use the subscripts to help us understand the concepts more explicitly, as in the question I linked above, because it is a first course in stochastic processes - I am not an expert, this is why I'm asking questions!

Comment: Some independence of the increments $B_1,B_2,B_3,\dots $ should be somehow an important part of the given data to be able to connect $\Bbb P(E_1)$ and $\Bbb P(E_2)$, when the events $E_1$, respectively $E_2$ stay for "paths of the worlds so that starting in $1$, respectively $2$, we also hit $0$ at some time $s$". (And setting $X_0=1$ makes starting in $2$ an event with zero probability, this was my point when saying that there is only on $E$, that $E_1$. Of course, we also want the other events, $E_2,E_3,\dots$, but then we let $X_0$ start somewhere, and constrain further data to its value.)

Comment: @dan_fulea I'm sorry but I really don't understand your comment at all, the independence of $B_t$ is important (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4801683/997524) hence why $\mathbb{P}(E_1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(E_2)$ are connected in this way... and I don't get what you're saying with the rest of your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but at the same time it was too long for a comment and maybe could help in finding the general solution.

First of all unfortunately none of the solutions you found can be probabilities, since for example if $p = \frac{1}{4}$ and $q = \frac{3}{4}$ then:
$$
\frac{1}{p}-\sqrt{\frac{q}{p}} = 4-\sqrt{3} > 1
$$
$$
\sqrt{\frac{q}{p}} = \sqrt{3} > 1
$$

Here I have proved that if we know that the value of $P(E_1)$ then we can compute $P(E_n)$ for all $n\geq 0$.

The stochastic process $X_t$ is often called the "lazy" random walk on the integer $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular we have that:
$$
P(E_1) = P\Bigl(\bigcup_{s=1}^{\infty}\{X_s = 0\}\Bigr).
$$
But we can also compute $P(E_1)$ using the law of total probability as follows:
$$
P(E_1) = P(E_1|B_1=1)P(B_1 = 1) + P(E_1|B_1 = 0)P(B_1 = 0) + P(E_1|B_1 = -1)P(B_1 = -1) \\
= \frac{p}{2}P(E_2)+\frac{1}{2}P(E_1)+\frac{q}{2}
$$
which implies that:
$$
P(E_2) = \frac{P(E_1)-q}{p}
$$
Similarly we can compute $P(E_2)$ as:
$$
P(E_2) = P(E_2|B_2=1)P(B_2 = 1) + P(E_2|B_2 = 0)P(B_2 = 0) + P(E_2|B_2 = -1)P(B_2 = -1) \\
= \frac{p}{2}P(E_3)+\frac{1}{2}P(E_2)+\frac{q}{2}P(E_1)
$$
From here we understand the 2-step recurrence:
$$
P(E_n) = \frac{P(E_{n-1})-qP(E_{n-2})}{p}
$$
with boundary conditions:
$$
P(E_0) = 1 \\
P(E_1) = E1
$$
Using the following code in Mathematica we can see that for $p\not=q$:

```
FullSimplify[
 RSolve[{a[n + 2] == (a[n + 1] - q*a[n])/p, a[1] == E1, a[0] == 1}, a,
   n]]
```

we find a general formula for $P(E_n)$, namely:
[[image: General formula for <span class=]$P(E_n)$ using $E_1$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQXLl.png)
while for $p = q = \frac{1}{2}$, using again the recurrence we find:
$$
P(E_n) = n(P(E_1)-1)+1
$$
from which we understand that $P(E_1)$ in this case has to be $1$ (since $P(E_n)\in[0,1]$ for all $n$).

Comment: Thank you for this, it's very detailed but I think above the scope of what I am expected to do. I think perhaps it's important for me to clarify that this question came in two parts, the first part being here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4801683/997524 . It seems obvious to me that the question is expecting me to use the relation $\mathbb{P}(E_2) = \mathbb{P}(E_1)^2$ in this second part. Your initial comment also is not particularly relevant as in my course we have seen examples like this and what my teacher has done is to disregard values of p and q for which the result does not hold.

Comment: This is why at the end of my question I said I was searching for some constraints on what particular solution is sensible (perhaps two solutions for different values of p and q). For example, for $p=q=0.5$ my solution of $\sqrt{\frac{q}{p}}$ in fact gives the same probability as yours, $1$, so I'm thinking this is a valid solution. This is the kind of thing I was looking for. And to know if I'm missing any solutions that could be found in the way I have been taught in my course so far.

Comment: Thank you @spooleey, I will think about it! I will try to better understand the problem and come up with a solution that fits what you are interested about.

Answer (score 0):

We have to assume that the variables $B_1,B_2,\dots, B_s,\dots$ are independent (as a family), else the mentioned argument does not work.

I am doing so in the sequel.

They also have the same distribution, as indicated, each member of the family takes the possible values $1,0,-1$ with probability respectively $p/2$, $1/2$, $q/2$.

(Such a situation is denoted by "iid" often in the courses and the posts, for independent, and identically distributed.)

The two degenerated cases

- $p=0$, $q=1$, we stay or go down with the sums,
- $p=1$, $q=0$, we stay or go up with the sums,
  have easy probabilities for $\Bbb P(E_1)$, they are $1$, and respectively $0$, and we (heuristically) expect them in the limit. Assume from now on $pq\ne 0$.

Let us denote the probability for the event $A(s)$ defined to cover all "paths of the world" so that at least one of the sums $B_s$, $B_s+B_{s+1}$, $B_s+B_{s+1}+B_{s+2}$, and so on, $B_s+B_{s+1}+\dots+B_t$, and so on, takes the value $-1$. Because of the assumed iid-property, all $A(s)$ have the same probability. And this value is also the same, conditioned by a given value of previous variables $B_1$, ... , $B_{s-1}$. Let us denote by $x$ this probability, so $x=\Bbb P(E_1)$ is the wanted number. Then with the OP argument we have:
$x = \frac 12(px^2+x+q)$, so the equation in $x$ to be solved is:
$$
px^2 - x + q=0\ .
$$
It has the two positive solutions $1$ and $\frac qp$.
Which one shall we take?

In case of $q\ge p$ we simply take the one, the probability cannot exceed this number.

---

---

From now on we assume $p>q$.
I don't see a way to distinguish between the two roots now by just simply conditioning on the outcome of $B_1$. Instead, i will give the usual "gambler ruin" argument.

First of all, we will replace the $(p,1/2,q)$-trinomial model with a binomial model, to have an easier situation. For this we let the many $B's$ show their outcomes in time, and "stop the clock" each time when there is a $+1$ or a $-1$ result. The first stop in time is when the first $\pm 1$ occurs, the second stop i time is when the second $\pm 1$ occurs, the third stop is when the third $\pm 1$ occurs, and so on. In a given situation, which is the probability for a next $+1$? This is the sum of all the probabilities for the chains $1$, $01$, $001$, and so on, this is:
$$
\frac p2\left(1+\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 18+\dots\right)=\frac p2\cdot 2=p\ .
$$
For a next $-1$ we can apply the same argument to get $q$, or pass the complement $1-q=p$ (since an infinite chain of zeros has probability zero).
So we work better in a binomial model with parameters $(p,q)$.

Fix some $N\ge 1$. Consider the following game. A gambler comes into the casino with an amount $k$, and plays "simple games" with outcomes $\pm 1$ till the ruin $0$ amount, or the amount $N$ is reached. Which is the win probability $P_k=P_k(N)$ (for each $k$ between $0$ and $N$)?
We have of course:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_0 &=0 &&\text{(Starting in zero, stops the game. No chance to win.)}\\
P_1 &= pP_2+qP_0\ ,\\
P_2 &= pP_3+qP_1\ ,\\
&\vdots\\
P_{N-1}&=pP_N+qP_{N-2}\ ,\\
P_N&=1\ .&&\text{(Starting in $N$, stops the game. It is a win.)}
\end{aligned}
$$
So for each $k$ with $0<k<N$ we have $(p+q)P_k=pP_{k+1}+qP_{k-1}$, leading to $p(P_{k+1}-P_k)=q(P_k-P_{k-1})$, so
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_2-P_1 &=\frac qp(P_1-P_0)=\frac qp P_1\ ,\\
P_3-P_2 &=\frac qp(P_2-P_1)=\left(\frac qp\right)^2 P_1\ ,\\
&\ \vdots\\
(P_N-P_{N-1})
&=\frac qp (P_{N-1}-P_{N-2})=\dots=\left(\frac qp\right)^{N-1} P_1\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{ and after adding }\\
1 &=P_N
\\
&=(P_N-P_{N-1})+\dots+(P_3-P_2)+(P_2-P_1)+P_1
\\
&=\left(\ \left(\frac qp\right)^{N-1} + \dots+ \left(\frac qp\right)^2
+\left(\frac qp\right)^1 +1 \right)P_1
=
\frac
{\displaystyle 1-\left(\frac qp\right)^N}
{\displaystyle 1-\left(\frac qp\right)}P_1
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So with a positive probability $P_1$, starting in $1$, the gambler wins.
Explicitly, $P_1$ is
$$
\bbox[lightyellow]{\qquad
P_1 = P_1(N) =
\frac
{\displaystyle 1-\left(\frac qp\right)}
{\displaystyle 1-\left(\frac qp\right)^N}
\qquad}
\ .
$$
*Example:* In case of $p=\frac {13}{25}$ and $q=\frac {12}{25}$, assume the gambler wants to reach $100$. And this happens indeed in mean with probability:
$$
P_1(100) = 
\frac
 {1-\frac{12/25}{13/25}}
 {1-\left(\frac{12/25}{13/25}\right)^{100}}
=
\frac{1-\frac {12}{13}}{1-\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)^{100}}
\approx
P_1(\infty)=
1-\frac {12}{13}=\frac 1{13}\ .
$$
In the limit, with $N\to\infty$, the probability to never reach zero is
$$
P_1(\infty)=\lim _N P_1(N)
=
1-\frac qp\ .
$$
And our $x$ is the probability to reach zero at some point, so it is $x=1-P_1=\frac qp$, "the right choice" among the two roots.